# Is it possible to configure current date for capybara-webkit driver?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, capybara-webkit

I'm testing a datepicker with rspec and capybara, some dates are disabled, and I think it would be easier to work with fixed test date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with fixed dates breaks down into the server side and the browser side.  For the server side you can use [Timecop](https://github.com/travisjeffery/timecop.git) to set the date you want the server to think it is. On the browser side you can use something like [Sinon.JS](http://sinonjs.org/) -  There's an article [here](http://makandracards.com/makandra/10753-mock-the-browser-time-or-time-zone-in-selenium-features) that talks about setting up your layout to automatically include sinon in tests where you're using timecop -- the article is from some time ago, but should be close enough.